# Retrieve selected value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jstl

Struggling with what should be some basic JavaScript.

A basic dropdown selector which correctly shows the selected value in a field -

```
<select id="State" onchange="getstate()">  <!--Call run() function-->
    <option value="'%'">All</option>
    <option value="228">Move</option>
    <option value="212">Clean</option>
    <option value="196">Cleaning</option>
    <option value="180">Ready</option>
    <option value="164">Occupied</option>
</select><br><br>

TextBox1<br>
<input type="text" id="srt" placeholder="get value on option select"><br>
   
<script>
function getstate() {
    document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("State").value;
    var selectedstate = String(document.getElementById("srt").value);
}
</script>

<%
System.out.println("the selected state is   "  + thisstate);
%>
```

I think I need something at the very start of the jsp, so I have -

```
<%          
   String thisstate=request.getParameter("selectedstate");         
%>
```

But the string variable selectedstate or thisstate (which I want to use in a JSTL select statement as a variable) only ever contains null.

I am obviosly doing something silly, assistance appreciated.

Comment: `selectedstate` is a local variable in that `getstate()` function. It will not be passed to the server. The "statename" input parameter *will* be passed to the server.

Comment: Thanks, how can I reference statename in my jsp (as a string variable)?

Comment: Well if you've decided not to post it as part of a form, you can't. Your JSP code runs **on the server**. Stuff gets from the page to the server by the content of a POST or GET HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks,, how can I populate a hidden form field with the value appearing in TextBox1

Comment: The way your original post populated the field was fine. The key is that if you're going to POST it, it needs a "name" attribute and it needs to be part of the form.

Comment: Thanks, but if I add a name it just ends up being null,  the value I need is effectively the id (the value appearing in TextBox1). Adding a dropdown slector and pulling out the selceted value into a string variable must be a lot easier than this.

Comment: Why not just include the `<select>` itself in the form? Really, for a question like this, it's best to explain concisely what you want to do, how you are trying, why you think that approach should work, and how it seems to not work as expected. I have no clue what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, I just want a dropdown selector and whatever is selected I need it to appear in a string variable so I can use it in a JSTL select statement i.e. where state like <%=chosen%>

Comment: So you understand that your JSTL/EL code runs **on your web server**, not in the web browser. In order for user interaction effects to be used by your server-side code, the browser has to issue an HTTP request so that your server runs the JSTL/EL page *again* and sends it back to the browser to reload the window. Or, you can have some kind of JavaScript-driven XHR mechanism. But in any case there must be network communication between the browser and your server in order for any relationship between page code and JSTL code to make any sense.

Comment: Also never any reason to do a String on a text field

Comment: Thanks again, was hoping that the form onchage function would have already updated correctly and sent whatever back was necessary, but it appears not. Sadly I can't find any examples of anyone doing what should be a simple 1 of 6 options selector.